# Form Load Events not processed when Form is called 2nd time

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Why doesn't the following work?

Two forms; first calls the second. Second form has a DataGridView on it - it has no columns in it, they're added by the program, along with a DataGridViewButtonColumn.

Calling Form2 the first time works fine. But calling it a second time, the buttons don't have any text.

```
' The first form - has one button, which calls Form2
Public Class Form1
    Friend fruit As New List(Of Fruit)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        fruit.Add(New Fruit("Apple", "Red"))
        fruit.Add(New Fruit("Orange", "Orange"))
        fruit.Add(New Fruit("Banana", "Yellow"))
        fruit.Add(New Fruit("Melon", "Red"))
        fruit.Add(New Fruit("Pear", "Green"))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Fruit
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property colour As String
    Public Sub New(newName As String, newColour As String)
        name = newName
        colour = newColour
    End Sub
End Class
```

Code for the second form is:

```
' Form2 has a button which closes the form, and a DataGridView
Public Class Form2
    Dim dataGridViewButtonColumn1 As DataGridViewButtonColumn
    Dim setupAlready As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dataGridViewButtonColumn1 = New DataGridViewButtonColumn
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Form1.fruit
        With dataGridViewButtonColumn1
            .Name = "ButtonCol"
            .UseColumnTextForButtonValue = False
        End With
        If Not setupAlready Then
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(dataGridViewButtonColumn1)
        End If
        For i As Integer = 0 To 4
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("ButtonCol").Value = "Hello"
        Next
        setupAlready = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        Debug.Print(String.Format("Col={0}, Row={1}, ColName={2}", e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name))
        If (DataGridView1.Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).Cells("ButtonCol").Value Is "Hello") Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.Item(e.RowIndex).Cells("ButtonCol").Value = "GoodBye"
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a convergence of several things causing this.  First, forms are classes and ought to be instanced explicitly.  Instead of `Form2.ShowDialog()` do this:

```
Using frm As New Form2        ' create instance
   frm.ShowDialog
   ' do something
End Using                     ' dialogs are also a resource
```

`Using`/ `.Dispose` is not needed with normal forms because when you Close them, they are disposed of.  Not so with dialogs since we unusually just Hide them so we can get info from them.

Next, the Form_Load event is only called the FIRST time you show the form. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx): `Occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.`

So by reusing a non disposed-of `Form2`, the Load event isnt called and the code in the Load event isnt executed.  It should work fine if you dispose of and create new form instances.  BTW this applies to all forms, not just dialogs.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, solves the problem nicely! (Sorry about slow response, was away for a week).