# Rows Not Highlighting in Data Grid View

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a simple selection form that displays a DataGridView and allows the user to select a record to process. I have a short sub routine that loops through the DGV and highlights rows based on a date comparison with a dictionary when the form loads. This works great the first time I open the form, but on subsequent form opens, the grid doesn't highlight. When I step through the code it looks like the rows should be highlighted, but when the form displays, nothing is highlighted.

Here is the code I'm using. I cannot figure out why it doesn't always work. Is there a better, more reliable way to accomplish this?

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvPending.Rows
    For Each pair In dPending
        If row.Cells.Item("ID").Value = pair.Key Then
            If row.Cells.Item("LAST_UPDATED").Value > pair.Value Then

                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond

            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: is that code IN formload - or called from there?  And how do you open/show the form the second+ times?

Comment: Sorry @Plutonix, that code is in a sub that is called from the form load event.

Comment: ....and how do you show the form the subsequent times?

Comment: @Plutonix the form is always displayed as a dialog from a button click on the main form: frm_pal_pending.ShowDialog()

Comment: in that case, see this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/24354798/1070452

Comment: when the form is not a dialog and you **are** just hiding it, just make the relevant code a public procedure like `RefreshDisplay` and call it before you do `.Show` (and of course call that proc from Form Load for the first time setup.  Good luck!