# "Constructor call is valid only as the first statement" error, but it is first statement

Tags: vb.net, oop

Getting error `Constructor call is valid only as the first statement in an instance constructor` when I try to call this constructor.  How can I correct?

I'm calling the constructor like this:

```
            Dim frmPull As Shipping.frmPullFromLocation
            frmPull = Shipping.frmPullFromLocation.New(datPickListDate, datRequestDate, datShipDate, intList, intQuantity, intRequest, strAdditionalInfo, strJobNumber, strItemCode)
            frmPull.ShowDialog()
```

.

```
 Public Sub New(ByVal datPickListDate As Date, ByVal datRequestDate As Date, ByVal datShipDate As Date, ByVal intList As Integer, ByVal intQuantity As Integer, ByVal intRequest As Integer, ByVal strAdditionalInfo As String, ByVal strJobNumber As String, ByVal strItemCode As String)
        MyBase.New()

        'Set local variables to the parameters passed in.
        Me.datPickListDate = datPickListDate
        Me.datRequestDate = datRequestDate
        Me.datShipDate = datShipDate
        Me.intList = intList
        Me.intQuantity = intQuantity
        Me.intRequest = intRequest
        Me.strAdditionalInfo = strAdditionalInfo
        Me.strJobNumber = strJobNumber
        Me.strItemCode = strItemCode

        Dim _frmPullFromLocation As frmPullFromLocation = Me
        AddHandler MyBase.Load, New EventHandler(AddressOf _frmPullFromLocation.frmPullFromLocation_Load)
        Me.blnShowMessage = True
        Me.InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
```

Comment: the next problem will be that you removed/ignored the `' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.` designer generated comment

Comment: @Plutonix -Seems to build and run ok... can you elaborate?

Comment: @Plutonix -They are vars, but are you suggesting its better practice to initialize after `Me.InitializeComponent()` call?

Comment: variables are fine, but to avoid any chance of a problem, I do all setup after it.  It prevents you from tacking on some `Me.TextBox...` reference in with the other code where it will destroy things.

Comment: @Plutonix -I don't normally make so many changes to the designer generated code, so I'm not used to this space.  Thanks, I'll definitely move the setup.

Comment: forms are resources though, and should be disposed.  [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24354883/1070452)

Comment: @Plutonix -Much appreciated, I'll change to `Using` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        Dim frmPull As Shipping.frmPullFromLocation
        frmPull = Shipping.frmPullFromLocation.New(datPickListDate, datRequestDate, datShipDate, intList, intQuantity, intRequest, strAdditionalInfo, strJobNumber, strItemCode)
        frmPull.ShowDialog()
```

Change that to

```
        Dim frmPull As Shipping.frmPullFromLocation
        frmPull = new Shipping.frmPullFromLocation(datPickListDate, datRequestDate, datShipDate, intList, intQuantity, intRequest, strAdditionalInfo, strJobNumber, strItemCode)
        '         ^^^ new!
        frmPull.ShowDialog()
```

You don't call New like a Shared or static method.

Comment: Oh.  I know that in general of course, but forgot in the moment.  How embarrassing....